# I am running Windows 7 and want to remove "Games Explorer"

Tags: windows-7

Very simply, I want it gone (deleted, removed from the hard drive), but Windows is not letting me.

I have checked many forums for this answer only to see another question:
"Why do you want to do this?" I find this **very** frustrating.

I just want it gone and I'm hoping someone can tell me how to do it.

Comment: So, why *do* you want to do this?

Comment: You can use [RT7Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) to remove it from the original installation medium (although this will require a re-install).  I removed it successfully without any downsides.

Comment: Often, on tech forums, someone will ask how to do something that seems trivial on its face, but may be very difficult to do or may have all sorts of effects that are not immediately obvious. In this case you're asking how to strip out a feature of Windows Explorer, and removing Windows Explorer would cripple your system. Presumably you already know how to delete the icon from the desktop and how to uninstall games. So, what is you're really trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's just as frustrating for us, believe me. Your question is akin to "How can I use a jackhammer to get the demons out of my grandmother's head?". The only thing a sane person wants to know is why anyone would try to do that. (It's difficult. It's dangerous. It's totally unclear what conceivable benefit there might be. And so on.)

Answer (score 13):

As Dennis points out, it's not possible to remove the "Games Explorer" system in Windows 7, as it's part of Explorer.  It's existence isn't really eating up any extra space or resources on your system.

You *can* uninstall Windows' games themselves via the `Windows Features` applet, and hide the Games entry from your Start Menu via the Start Menu's properties.

There's a nice tutorial on how to perform these actions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/23286/quick-tip-turn-off-games-in-windows-7/).

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but this is impossible.

Source: [Windows 7 Secrets - Paul Thurrott, Rafael Rivera - Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=1EXt2U84WZ0C&pg=SA16-PA18&dq="cannot+uninstall+Games+Explorer"&f=false)

Comment: btw @Dennis this is what I see http://i.stack.imgur.com/SjkjJ.png

Comment: @Sathya the link needs the `.py` removed

Comment: @TobiasKienzler it works fine with the extension. The high page views caused the error to be shown

Comment: @Sathya: I removed the `ei=` and `ved=` parts of the URL that I think are causing the limitation.

Comment: @Dennis I'd clicked the same URL which was originally linked, didn't get the error. Guess the limits are reset periodically

Comment: @Sathya: I don't know how it works exactly, but the `ei=` and `ved=` parts were linked to my specific search. I *hope* that there are no further restrictions.

Comment: @Dennis I don't see anything in the link about it being impossible. Perhaps you could quote the relevant part in this answer?

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the others trying to push their opinion, I know why you want this:

1. Simply delete (using Unlocker app, if needed) all the DLLs beginning with gameux from the windows folders (system32, syswo64, and winsxs).

You'll no longer be annoyed by the game starting delay bug

Obs.1: Whenever you try to open the games explorer, a error message will come up

Obs.2: If you don't delete from winsxs, the SFC might restore the file

Obs.3: Deleting things from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameUX **does not work**

Comment: Obs.4: Renaming game exe to something else, if possible, will bypass GameUX tunneling.
What I've noticed is that GameUX phones home, now in 2020 to some unreachable Microsoft address that stays at SYN_SENT, i.e. forever. Maybe that's the issue. Note, even if manually update and no other download or collect option is enabled.

Comment: Obs.5: taking control of permissions over subkey S-1-... under GameUX mentioned in Obs.3, and removing all permissions for read, list etc, sans OWNER setting permissions, will fix the issue as well.

Comment: Obs.6: extending Obs.5: However, if a user would restrict permission per game key, the ones under S-1-... starting with an {, Game Explorer will work, will not list that particular game and will fix the issue as well. This would be the best solution as to not delete files, nor break Game Explorer, nor rename main game exe and still make it work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to download a free third party software "UnlockIt" published by EMCO . After installing the application, locate the path of game explorer "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games" drag and drop it to the applicaion. Then just click "Delete" on the bar. And that's all